# AspNet MVC - return RedirectToAction is not working with image upload (if file.SaveAs gets called)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

`return RedirectToAction` is not working if `imageUpload.SaveAs(path);` executed otherwise it does working (I mean if I do not select any image it will not reach the line `imageUpload.SaveAs(path);`).

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewEmployee(Employee emplView, HttpPostedFileBase imageUpload)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var mod = new PersonalDetailsViewModel(emplView);
            return View("AddEmployee", mod);
        }
        if (imageUpload != null && imageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = emplView.EmployeeId + "_" + Path.GetFileName(imageUpload.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fileName);

            imageUpload.SaveAs(path);
            emplView.Photograph = fileName;
        }
        _dbContext.Employees.Add(emplView);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("PersonalDetails", new { id = emplView.EmployeeId });
    }
```

I checked with debugger, it is reaching to the last line and executing but not redirecting to the action method. I don't know where I am doing wrong?

I checked within following method of `Global.asax` for any hidden error, but there wasn't any:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    }
```

Comment: The exception might be happening outside of the ASP.NET pipeline, so there's no guarantee that Application_Error will catch it. Try wrapping the save image code in a try/catch and/Or add ELMAH to the project.

Comment: What is happening now ? What result are you actually getting ? Is there an exception ?

Comment: After RedirectToAction - whether you are able to debug "PersonalDetails" method or it is just terminating?

Comment: No chance at all, there wasn't any exception in catch and still executing successfully but not redirecting...

Comment: @Rex No not able to debug "PersonalDetails" it is not reaching there.

Comment: Is it calling the SaveChanges ? Did you put a breakpoint in the sourcecode and see which lines are executing ?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the image upload and not another MVC routing related issue? The action you are redirecting to doesn't need any specific attributes that may be going stale between different tests? (Any Auth or custom decorations?)  The id it's sending as well is there each time, tried with same id? I mean you probably have checked during debugging already but might as well throw it out there. Routing can be spooky sometimes, it's worth bringing up to make sure bases are covered when checking for answers.

Comment: @Shyju Yeah, It is saving the record and image to the given path, but only not doing the redirection.

Comment: @NardDog I don't think if there is the routing issue, as if I do not select the file in file upload control or just comment the SaveAs line then it is doing the job. If it become the routing issue then it must not work at all even for uploading the image or not.

Comment: How are you posting to this method? (are you using ajax?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, I am not using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps move your:
imageUpload.SaveAs(path);
to an aSync method allowing the rest of the code to execute without waiting for the image upload process to finish. I am suspecting you are getting collusion for the image upload request while trying to give a response from your controller.

Comment: I doubt so, but could you decorate the exact scenario (code) to get it. you can do the decoration on my given code.

Comment: Even I don't think so that this could be the cause, since it worked for me.

Comment: @wkhaksar If saving the employee info works but the image upload is not saving and you are killing time, I would make two functions and make them each do one thing (Single Responsibility)
<br />
- first Save() the new Employee <br />
- next allow the user to Upload an Image (even use Ajax with an async method for this if you want to be fancy)<br />
- then send them to the Personal Details (although this is where I would allow them to upload an image, seems more proper here.)<br />

Comment: My working sample code is an extract from your code excluding _dbContext operations and just "imageUpload" parameter + related code( save image and re-direct action).